# calling a servlet which does not return anything...from a jsp while loading

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I need to call a servlet during a page load(abc.jsp). The Servlet would not return anything.It just makes some updates to a database.

If I use href to call the servlet, abc.jsp does not get loaded as the servlet does not return anything.

If I use form submit(empty form with no fields) to call the servlet and call it during onload event of the abc.jsp, that does makes a call to the servlet but abc.jsp will not be loaded.

What is the best way to call the servlet which does not return anything and still load abc.jsp ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)  request during page loade time:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "myServlet" );
});
```

Comment: thanks...seems to be working...testing more...do you think this fix will work for all browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html). As Specification says:

> Filters differ from web components in that filters usually do not themselves create a response. Instead, a filter provides functionality that can be “attached” to any kind of web resource. Consequently, a filter should not have any dependencies on a web resource for which it is acting as a filter; this way, it can be composed with more than one type of web resource.